# Open Windows Form on click of Tray Icon in windows Service

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, taskbar, notifyicon

I want to create windows service along with Notify icon. After install of Windows service notify icon will show in notification bar till windows service not terminate. On Click of Notify Icon Open Windows Form.

but the problem is that -> Notify Icon not constantly visible

Is there any other way to solved this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is the service always running?

Comment: yes. and i want notify icon visible till service not terminate.

Comment: Is your service is running through timer?

Comment: @PraveenM No , No use of timer in service